# How do I do git clone with drush to download the HEAD version of a module?

Tags: drush, version-control

Is there any way to clone or pull the HEAD version of a module in drupal.org git repository?

For example, if I'm on Drupal 7, and the last branch of Views is 3, I would like to do:

```
drush git-clone views
```

to achieve something equivalent to:

```
cd sites/all/modules/
git clone --recursive --branch 7.x-3.x http://git.drupal.org/project/views.git
```

Ideally, using `drush git-clone views-3x` should clone the 3.x branch explicitly.

Is this possible or am I dreaming? This would be really useful for developing.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
drush dl views-7.x-3.x --package-handler=git_drupalorg
```

**Update:**

True, if there are commits after the dev release was packaged, you will need to run `git pull` to advance to HEAD after checking out via drush dl.  If there is no packaged dev release, and Drush checks out a stable release, then you need to run `git checkout 7.x-3.x` after drush dl.

There is no Drush command to do a verbatim git clone; part of the "value add" of drush dl is that it grabs published releases.  If git clone is what you want, perhaps a short bash script would be your best solution.  Something like this:

**Usage:**

```
$ clonedev views 3
```

**Example script:**

```
#!/bin/bash

MODULE=$1
VERSION=$2

DRUPAL=$(drush status "Drupal Version" --pipe | sed -e 's/\..*//')
if [ -n $DRUPAL ] ; then
  cd $(drush drupal-directory modules)
else
  DRUPAL=7
fi

git clone --recursive --branch $DRUPAL.x-$VERSION.x http://git.drupal.org/project/$MODULE.git
```

Modify to suit.

Comment: I've just tried it, and it downloads the latest dev release, not HEAD. And if there is no dev release available, it downloads the latest recommended or supported release.

Comment: Okay, see updated answer.